# Problems with recursion when using fff_shift

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm writing a program to read in data from a list, Fourier transform and shift it before plotting. So far, the code takes the spectroscopy data from the DICOM file and puts it into a list, with each element an array containing the values of each individual FID/spectra.

```
from pylab import *
import dicom

plan=dicom.read_file("")

all_points = array(plan.SpectroscopyData)
cmplx_data = all_points[0::2] + 1j*all_points[1::2]
frames = int(plan.NumberOfFrames)
fid_pts = len(cmplx_data)/frames

fid_list = []
for fidN in arange(frames):
    offset = fidN * fid_pts 
    current_fid = cmplx_data[offset:offset+fid_pts]
    fid_list.append(current_fid)
```

This works fine to group the data, but I encounter problems when trying to use the arrays generated. Firstly, when trying to display only the complex part of the data, for example:

```
plot(complex(fid_list[0]))
```

Returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/dominicc/Desktop/<ipython-input-37-4146b7fbfd7c> in <module>()
----> 1 plot(complex(fid_list[0]))

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Secondly, and most importantly though, I encounter infinite recursion when trying to plot the zero-frequency shift of the FFTed data:

```
plot(fftshift(fft(fid_list[0])))
```

Getting the following error

```
/home/dominicc/Desktop/New_Script.py in fftshift(fid_in)
     23 
     24 def fftshift(fid_in):
---> 25         fft_fid_in = fft(fid_in)
     26         plot(fftshift(fft_fid_in))
     27         show()

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack.pyc in fft(a, n, axis)
    162     """
    163 
--> 164     return _raw_fft(a, n, axis, fftpack.cffti, fftpack.cfftf, _fft_cache)
    165 
    166 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack.pyc in _raw_fft(a, n, axis, init_function, work_function, fft_cache)
     43 def _raw_fft(a, n=None, axis=-1, init_function=fftpack.cffti,
     44              work_function=fftpack.cfftf, fft_cache = _fft_cache ):
---> 45     a = asarray(a)
     46 
     47     if n is None:

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can anyone suggest ways to improve my code so as to avoid these problems? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding another for loop that Fourier transformed the data before the fftshit:

```
fft_list = []
for i in range(0, frames):
    current_fid = fft(fid_list[i])
    fft_list.append(current_fid)
```

Answer (score 1):

**First error**

In your for loop you have:

```
current_fid = cmplx_data[offset:offset+fid_pts]
fid_list.append(current_fid)
```

fid is thus a multidimensional list. This is the case because `[foo,bar].append([some,list])` results in `[foo,bar,[some,list]]`

`complex(fid_list[0])` expects any lists it gets to be of length 1. The line `current_fid = cmplx_data[offset:offset+fid_pts]` means that fid_list[0] is of length `fid_pts`

**Second Error**

So a recursive function needs to take care of two branches internally. One is the terminating branch (this stops things from spiralling off into infinity), and the other branch is the one that attempts the before-mentioned spiralling.

fftshift does not take care of the terminating branch so you need to add some code for that.

Rewrite the function like so and run it to see an illustration of this point:

```
def fftshift(fid_in):
    print('fftshift 1')
    fft_fid_in = fft(fid_in)
    print('fftshift 2')
    foo = fftshift(fft_fid_in)
    print(' fftshift3')
```

This will print:

```
fftshift 1
fftshift 2
fftshift 1
fftshift 2
fftshift 1
fftshift 2
etc etc recursion error
```

The simplest form of a recursive function is:

```
def my_recursive_fn(foo):
    if some_condition:   #the terminating condition
        return bar #this should NOT call my_recursive_fn in any way
    moo = do_processing(foo)
    return my_recursive_fn(foo)


    plot(foo)
    show()
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot with my understanding of both errors. As a complete novice to programming though, I'm struggling to come up with a function that would allow me to do the fftshift as desired. Could you possibly suggest a more specific solution to the problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I haven't worked with fourier stuff for years so I cant very easily... can you describe what you are trying to pull off in plain english?

Comment: It's okay. I've solved the problem by using a for loop to generate a new list that had already been transformed. I don't know why I didn't think to do it sooner! Thanks for the explanation of why the errors occurred, helped a lot.

Comment: @docar: You are welcome. It's nice to post your answer and mark it as correct